# Changing absolute positioned text div through jQuery, without changing it's position

Tags: jquery, css-position

I am new to html, css and javascript. What I am trying to do is:

Adding a white background with some text, on the right side of an image.
I have positioned the white bg div and text as absolute.

I am getting it right so far, but when I change the text through a jquery function, it moves the text div to its normal position(like it should be if I don't make it absolute).

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
    <div id="block_contact" class="block_contact">  
    <img id="notesImg" src="images/love_notes/1.jpg" onload=""/> 
    <div id="white_bg_right">
    </div>
    <div id="notes_text_div">
    <p id="notes_text">What a pleasant surprise!</p>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    #white_bg_right {
    width:240px;
    height:362px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    opacity:0.5;

    position:absolute;
    top:16px;
    left:329px;

    }

    #notes_text_div {
    width:210px;
    height:362px;
    position:absolute;
    left:344px;

    }
    #notes_text{
    width:210px;
    height:362px;

    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

jQuery Function:

```
$("#notes_text").html("<p>dummy text</p>");
```

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would start with this:

```
#block_contact { position: relative; }
```

Any absolutely positioned child elements will start from the top-left corner of **#block_contact**, instead of the top-left corner of the window.

Try it and see if it fixes anything, I don't have any other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is change the text, you don't need the `<p>` tags in your jQuery function call:

```
$("#notes_text").html("dummy text");
```

If you want those tags for some reason, then you will need some CSS to set `display:table-cell`, like you do with `#notes_text`.  By default, `<p>` tags use `display:block`.